# How to use roman numerals for backup slides on beamer?

Tags: beamer, roman-numerals

I'm making a LaTeX presentation using beamer, and I'd like to prepare some slides for possible questions I can be asked for.

I find how to ignore slides numbering in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/732902/ignoring-page-numbers-in-backup-slides), but I don't like the result, which is roughly the following:

> Slide 1/n Slide 2/n...Slide n/n [from here questions slide] Slide (n+1)/n Slide (n+2)/n

What I would achieve is roughly the following:

> Slide 1/n Slide 2/n...Slide n/n [from here questions slide] Slide I Slide II

How can I achieve it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following example:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\setbeamertemplate{footline}[page number]

\defbeamertemplate{footline}{page number appendix}
{%
  \hfill%
  \usebeamercolor[fg]{page number in head/foot}%
  \usebeamerfont{page number in head/foot}%
  \insertpagenumber\kern1em\vskip2pt%
}
\makeatletter
\g@addto@macro\appendix{%
  \setbeamertemplate{footline}[page number appendix]%
  \renewcommand*{\insertpagenumber}{%
    \Roman{framenumber}%
  }%
}
\makeatother

\usepackage{appendixnumberbeamer}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}A\end{frame}
\begin{frame}B\end{frame}
\begin{frame}C\end{frame}
\appendix
\begin{frame}D\end{frame}
\begin{frame}E\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

has the following page numbers in the footline:
`1/3`, `2/3`, `3/3`, `I`, `II`.

Comment: Not working for me. Do I have to do anything special? Which latex engine?

Comment: @Marcel Also after almost eight years, it is working with `beamer 2020/11/26 v3.60` (pdfLaTeX, LuaLaTeX, XeLaTeX). Make a new question with the minimal example, the versions, at least from `beamer` and the engine. Explain the "not-working" part.