# Convert \insertappendixendpage to Roman in beamer

Tags: beamer, counters

I want to have Roman page numbers (not frame numbers) in the appendix section both for the current and for the total page count, i.e. in the footline of my slides, I want:

```
1/4, 2/4, 3/4, 4/4
% appendix starts here
I/III, II/III, III/III
```

A similar thing has been asked in [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/119515/how-to-use-roman-numerals-for-backup-slides-on-beamer) question, but the total page count is missing in the appendix, i.e. it only gives `I II III`.

Here's my code:

```
% !TeX program = lualatex
\documentclass[aspectratio=169,t]{beamer}
\usetheme{Malmoe}
\usecolortheme{beaver}

\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}

% select page indicator style
\newcommand{\pagetracker}{%
    \insertpagenumber{} / \insertpresentationendpage%
}

\setbeamertemplate{footline}{
    \hfill\pagetracker\hspace*{1ex}
}

\usepackage{appendixnumberbeamer}

% switch to Roman numbering in appendix
\makeatletter
\g@addto@macro\appendix{
    \pagenumbering{Roman}
    \renewcommand*{\pagetracker}{%
        \insertpagenumber{} / \insertappendixendpage%
    }%
}%
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{frame}
        \only<1>{A1}
        \only<2>{A2}
    \end{frame}

    \begin{frame}
        \only<1>{B1}
        \only<2>{B2}
    \end{frame}

    \appendix
    
    \begin{frame}
        \only<1>{Appendix C1}
        \only<2>{Appendix C2}
    \end{frame}

    \begin{frame}
        \only<1>{Appendix D1}
        \only<2>{Appendix D2}
    \end{frame} 

    \begin{frame}
        \only<1>{Appendix E1}
        \only<2>{Appendix E2}
    \end{frame}
        
\end{document}
```

How can I convert the output of `\insertappendixendpage` to Roman to make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
% !TeX program = lualatex
\documentclass[aspectratio=169,t]{beamer}
\usetheme{Malmoe}
\usecolortheme{beaver}

\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}

% select page indicator style
\newcommand{\pagetracker}{%
    \insertpagenumber{} / \insertpresentationendpage%
}

\setbeamertemplate{footline}{
    \hfill\pagetracker\hspace*{1ex}
}

\usepackage{appendixnumberbeamer}

% switch to Roman numbering in appendix
\makeatletter
\g@addto@macro\appendix{
    \setcounter{page}{1}
    \renewcommand*{\pagetracker}{%
        \@Roman{\value{page}} / \@Roman{\beamer@endpageofdocument}%
    }%
}%
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{frame}
        \only<1>{A1}
        \only<2>{A2}
    \end{frame}

    \begin{frame}
        \only<1>{B1}
        \only<2>{B2}
    \end{frame}

    \appendix
    
    \begin{frame}
        \only<1>{Appendix C1}
        \only<2>{Appendix C2}
    \end{frame}

    \begin{frame}
        \only<1>{Appendix D1}
        \only<2>{Appendix D2}
    \end{frame} 

    \begin{frame}
        \only<1>{Appendix E1}
        \only<2>{Appendix E2}
    \end{frame}
        
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you, that is almost it! Any way to reset the page counter in the appendix so that the roman numbers count from `I`?

Comment: @Christoph90 see my edited answer

Comment: Thank you very much, it's perfect.

Comment: @Christoph90 You're welcome!